# FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() is not signing out user

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

FirebaseAuth.getInstance.signOut() method does not work.
Everytime I signout I end up going back to PostActivity because FirebaseAuth.getInstance() is not null

signout method, goes back to LoginActivity from ProfileActivity  to login another user

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.menu_logout){
            Log.i(TAG,"user wants to logout")
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

In LoginActivty, this checks if user is already signed in

```
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        //check if already signed in
        if(auth != null){
            goPostsActivity()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` will never be null. Instead, you have to check for `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` like this:

```
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        //check if already signed in
        if(auth != null){
            goPostsActivity()
        }
```